# How to give non-changing unique key to siblings in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been struggling for over an hour but couldn't find the solution.

The data structure is like

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1, title: 'something', tags: ['first', 'second', 'third'] },
  { id: 2, title: 'something', tags: ['first', 'second', 'third'] },
  { id: 3, title: 'something', tags: ['first', 'second', 'third'] },
];
```

And I wanna render `Tag` components for each item of `arr` using `map` function, like below.

```js
const Item = ({ item }) => (
  <article>
    <h1>{item.title}</h1>
    <ul>
      {item.tags.map(tag => (
        <Tag key={?} tag={tag} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  </article>
);
```

But what can I use for `key` except the index in an array?

I tried `Date.now()` but it's not unique for sibling nodes, and I also tried `Math.random()` and it worked, but it will change every time `Item` re-renders.
There are some libraries for this as far as I know but I heard they change too when re-rendering.

Comment: Will the tags be unique for each item?

Comment: Can you tell us why `index` cannot be used?

Comment: @jagannathbhat - It's [an anti-pattern](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) that can lead to broken rendering. (That article is also linked from [the documentation on keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).)

Comment: @JoeLissner I'm not sure If I understood what you meant though, one group of tags belong to each item and I wanna make each of those tags unique.

Comment: I think what @JoeLissner was asking is if there is a chance `tags` could contain duplicate elements like `['first', 'first', 'second', 'third']`

Comment: @jagannathbhat oh there wasn't any condition regarding that, but now I'm thinking of restricting duplication 

Comment: If there's no duplication then @T.J.Crowder 's solution works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what can I use for key except the index in an array?

For the items (`article` instances), you'd use their `id`. (I assume those are unique in the array.)

For the tags, use the tag itself. (I'm inferring from the name "tag" that you don't have the same tag repeated in the same array.)

```
const Item = ({ item }) => (
  <article key={item.id}>
  {/*      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */}
    <h1>{item.title}</h1>
    <ul>
      {item.tags.map(tag => (
        <Tag key={tag} tag={tag} />
        {/*  ^^^^^^^^^ */}
      ))}
    </ul>
  </article>
);
```

Keys only have to be unique between siblings (e.g., elements in the array you're mapping), they don't have to be globally unique ([documentation link](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings)).

Comment: I think using `tag` for key is a good idea if I don't allow users to create a same tag! thank you!

Answer (score -1):

hmmm someone suggested to use tag.id, I don't think that's a thing in your code. I think they meant arr.id, but to do that I think you'd need to do something along the lines of:

```
  {item.map((items, index) => (
    <Tag key={items.id} tag={items.tag} />
  ))}
```

Comment: He is iterating over the item's tags, not the items themself in his code example.

Comment: True, my bad.  

In that case, if he could change the data structure (Idk if that's possible for him), he could use an array of objects instead of an array. That way he can have a tag id.